# Install different versions of Phonegap app on same device?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-cli

We are developing an app using Phonegap.  We have several different versions stored as different git branches that are sorta being developed simultaneously.  What I would like to do is be able to `cordova build android` one branch, install on device, switch branches, `cordova build android` on the new branch, install on device, and have these two builds be treated as two different apps.  What do I need to change in the different branches to make this happen?  I've tried changing app name in `config.xml` but it still treats the build as an update rather than a new install.

Comment: You can change the package name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the id attribute in the widget element. For example, if your current app has the id `com.example.app` you could make one branch use `com.example.otherapp` as its id. Android will then treat them as different apps.